# BIND server cannot resolve us3.php.net!

Tags: bind, troubleshooting, nameserver

My caching nameserver (BIND 9.3.6-P1) cannot contact 216.194.113.11 or 216.194.113.12 over UDP port 53 for some unknown reason. This prevents anyone at my office from resolving names such as phpnet-mirror.tierfour.com. However our nameserver successfully resolves all other names. How can I troubleshoot this issue? Output from dig:

```
[jnet@Stan ~]$ dig @216.194.113.11 VERSASERVERS.NET

; <<>> DiG 9.4.3-P1 <<>> @216.194.113.11 VERSASERVERS.NET
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

(EDIT: Changed description of the problem, thanks to ko-dos: This is not an issue with *.php.net, it is an issue with the above nameservers specifically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`us2` is a cname for `php.he.net`. `us3` on the other hand is a cname for phpnet-mirror.tierfour.com. These are different SOA and nameservers.

Comment: Thank you for that! Sure enough, it's tierfour.com that my nameserver cannot resolve.